# How to use <del>/line-through to <select><option> in the part of the text

Tags: html, css

the example it is work, but I want to use part of the text.

```
.line-through {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
<select class="line-through">
  <option>test text</option>
</select>
```

like this:

```
<select>
  <option>test <span  class="line-through">text</span></option>
</select>
```

or

```
 <select>
    <option>test <del>text</del></option>
 </select>
```

It not work, is there any way to achieve?

Comment: You cannot have other elements inside of `option` tags, so your `span` will be ignored. Your best bet is to create a mock drop-down and style it that way. Something like this: http://pepsized.com/demo/css-only-alternative-to-the-select-element-demo/

Comment: thank,I know, other elements will be ignored,but I hope want to  try a simple design the <select>.